# How to make smooth circles on basemap projections in Matplotlib by Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm not advanced user of Python, but due to my scientific work I got tasks to plot some graphs with Matplotlib. 
Now I have to draw smooth-deformed according to the basemap projection, circles around given point. But in the result I got circles with broken lines:

[image: Here the image of broken circle]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_mwd(RA,Dec,org=0,title='GCS', projection='aitoff'):

    x = np.remainder(RA+360-org,360) # shift RA values
    ind = x>180
    x[ind] -=360    # scale conversion to [-180, 180]
    x=-x    # reverse the scale: East to the left
    tick_labels = np.array([150, 120, 90, 60, 30, 0, 330, 300, 270, 240, 210])
    tick_labels = np.remainder(tick_labels+360+org,360)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=projection, axisbg ='LightCyan')
    ax.scatter(np.radians(x),np.radians(Dec), s = 30, c = 'k', marker = '.')  # convert degrees to radians
    ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels)     # we add the scale on the x axis
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.title.set_fontsize(15)
    ax.xaxis.label.set_fontsize(12)
    ax.yaxis.label.set_fontsize(12)
    ax.grid(color='tab:gray', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.2)
    circle1 = plt.Circle((np.radians(35),np.radians(30)), np.radians(40), color='g', fill = False) # Circle parameters
    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.add_artist(circle1)

coord = np.array([(325,30)]) # coordinates that will be ploted
plot_mwd(coord[:,0],coord[:,1], org=0, title ='GCS', projection ='aitoff')   

plt.show()
```

Comment: See this tutorial, which does exactly this: http://www.geophysique.be/2011/02/20/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-09-drawing-circles/

Comment: Thanks for that, i'll try to convert this into my goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `plt.Circle()` does not allow to specify the number of vertexes to plot. So, you need to write up your own code. Here is my code that you may try:

```
# Plot circle with 36 vertexes
phi = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, 36)  #36 points
r = np.radians(40)
x = np.radians(35) + r*np.cos(phi)
y = np.radians(30) + r*np.sin(phi)
ax.plot(x, y, color="g")
```

Use my code in place of yours 2 lines:

```
circle1 = plt.Circle((np.radians(35), np.radians(30)), np.radians(40), color='g', fill = False)  # Circle parameters
ax.add_artist(circle1)
```

The resulting image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you are my savior. I hope this will be enough for my supervisor.